# Contact Lists not working in Outlook after moving to Office 365 for email

Tags: office-365, outlook, contacts

We have SBS2011 server where we shut down exchange and moved the email to Office 365, we are using Azure AD Connect to do a one way sync of our users to O365.

We are still using SharePoint (AKA, CompanyWeb) part of SBS. Since the move to O365 we can't get our Contact lists to work in Outlook.

If we browse to them IE and choose connect to Outlook, it goes through the process and the list gets added, but then it throws up the Send/Receive tab and gives this error.

> Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80004005) : 'An error occurred in
>   this SharePoint List (MAPD - Medicare Contact List). Try updating the
>   folder again. If the problem continues, contact the SharePoint site
>   administrator.  HTTP 500.

The server returned the following error message:

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.'

---

If you close out of that and click on the list in Outlook it shows up empty.

This is happening with fully updated copies of both Office 2013 and 2016 Home and Business and with all of our Contact lists not just a specific one.

A google search isn't turning up much. This result from MS describes it exactly, but they just tell you to remove the list and not how to fix it if it still in use.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2812355/outlook-send-receive-errors-http-0--http-404--http-500

Other than that I am not turning up much of anything. Any ideas?